# OnPropertyChanged Event Handler

Tags: c#, events, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am writing an application for Windows Phone.  I have a variable result which stores the response sent by a server after a request from the Windows Phone app.

I have a class called **request** which generates the request and receives the response.  I want to check when the **result** variable changes to that I can do some further processing on my application.

Here is the request class:

```
namespace PhoneApp1
{
    public class Request: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string data;
        public string result = "test";

        public Request()
        {

        }

        public string Result
        {
            get
            {
                return result;
            }
            set
            {
                if (this.result == value)
                {
                    return;
                }
                this.result = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Result");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public void doRequest(string parameters, string URL)
        {
            data = parameters;

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);
        }

        public void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
        {
            HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
            Stream postStream = myRequest.EndGetRequestStream(callbackResult);
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

            postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            postStream.Close();

            myRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponsetStreamCallback), myRequest);
        }

        public void GetResponsetStreamCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);

            StreamReader httpWebStreamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            result = httpWebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I implemented an OnPropertyChanged event handler on the **result variable**.

Here is the code from where I am creating an instance of the class to do the request:

```
                    **//Log-in Button Event Handler**
                    Request req = new Request();
                    req.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(req_PropertyChanged);
                    req.doRequest("function=LogIn&username=" + username + "&password=" + password, "http://localhost:4000/Handler.ashx");
                }
            }
        }**//End of Log-in Button Event Handler**

        public void req_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string result = ((Request)sender).Result;

            if (result.Equals("True") || result.Equals("true"))
            {
                PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["Username"] = username;
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Authenticated.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The log-in details are invalid!");
            }
        }
```

For some reason or another, nothing happens when I click the log-in button.  No message box, no redirection, not even an exception.  I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.  Please help me.  I have wasted these past two hours trying to solve this problem.

Why is the req_PropertyChanged code not executing, even though I know that the **result** variable is changing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PropertyChanged` is not magic.
It will only fire if you explicitly raise the event.

You do raise the event in your `Result` setter, but you aren't calling that.
When you write `result = httpWebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();`, you set the field directly, without running the property setter.
Thus, the event never fires.

Comment: So how can I rewrite the line?  Sorry but I am very new to these concepts.

Comment: Ok I solved that part.  I just used Result = httpWebStreamReader.ReadToEnd()

Comment: Exactly. You need to set the property.